# How to install a Wireless Epson WF3640 Printer on Elementary OS?

Tags: printer

I have managed to install EPSON WF 3640 printer over USB driver.

But how do I install EPSON WF 3640 printer over wireless please ? Any help or pointers pls.

Thanks 
S

Answer (score 0):

When you search printers on the applications menu, choose it and press add printer does your printer appear on the network printers?

Comment: Hi, no my Epson wf3640 printer does not appear in the wireless printer options.

Comment: Do you have the computer and the printer connected to the same router? On your printer display does it show it's connected to your router? I'm asking this because it should show on the network printers even if you don't have the drivers. The drivers page is here: " http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/ ".  It shows that your printer have linux drivers. You could try to install the drivers and then see if it starts to show on the network printers.

Comment: Hello, I tried it but it does not recognise it as wireless printer.

Comment: It will only show when I connect using is cable. But it does not show the printer over wireless network.

Comment: That is strange.  Have you tried to download an Ubuntu image and run it from USB to see if it works?  I also have an Epson printer and it have worked on 14.04 and 16.04.

Comment: Okay I have now removed elementary os and replaced with ubuntu. The printer works fine.